# why does my hp laptop start automatically after shutting it down?

Tags: hp, autostart

I am a new Ubuntu user. I have been using another distribution, but today I  have decided to switch to Ubuntu. after installing, I powered my computer off. later, I installed the updates and I ran upgrading. Once I finished upgrading and updating processes, I powered off my computer. but it suddenly auto-powered itself, in the first glance I thought its me who hit the restart button. I powered it off again, and it powered itself on again automatically. Is there any solution for this issue?

I am uisng HP Probook 640

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: what was the previous distro were you using, and what distro of ubuntu are you running now?  Did you have this issue on your computer with the previous version?  Have you checked syslogs for any errors or warnings?

Comment: I was using linux mint cinnamon, and I had no issues with it, I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS now.

I found these in syslogs : gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

Comment: by the by, before updating and upgrading, it worked fine. the auto-power on issue emerged only after upgrading and updating

Comment: Just after it cones up, `sudo journalctl  --since="-15 minutes"` will show the logs. Do you have swap? `free` will show. Read `man pm-is-supported`. (In this area of Ubuntu, "pm" stands for "Power Management").

Comment: @waltinator I do not have any swap.I do not have any problems with power. the issue that I have now is that Power-off button works similarly as Restart button. and the only way to stop my computer now from powering-on itself automatically is to remove the battery. I had not had this issue while running under Linux mint which I had been using for two years.

Comment: Do you have any external devices connected to your laptop (mouse, keyboard, etc.)?

Comment: Are you able to create a live boot external drive with the same version?  If so I would try booting up with that to see if the error replicates.

Comment: @PJ Singh  Hi Bro, I do not have anything plugged in. It is quite the opposite each time I want to power off my computer I have to plug in a USB to prevent my machine to power on itself automatically. In other words,  if no usb key is plugged in while powering my laptop off, it auto-powers itself.